# How to split string with colons but not if it is a time?

Tags: python, regex

Given some long string:

```
s = "something blah blah: but it isn't 4:00 or 16:00 yet, how should we do this: that's it"
```

I want to be able to get a returning string with:

```
s = "something blah blah:\n but it isn't 4:00 or 16:00 yet, how should we do this:\n that's it"
```

UPDATE THIS IS MY CODE (not working because it either splits the string or not at all):

```
def tokenize_time(s):
    #check if time is in string
    if re.search(ur"([:])", s):
        if not re.search(ur"([0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])", s):
            s = re.sub(':', ':\n', s)
    return s
```

Comment: Have you tried writing such a regular expression yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried that isn't working

Comment: @CertainPerformance my code currently either splits the string or not at all... having trouble with conditionals and regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it isn't working:**
You're asking it to search the entire string `s` for one pattern, `ur"([:])"`.

If a match is found, you want it to search the entire string `s` again, but this time for the pattern `ur"([0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])"`.

If the first pattern is found, but the second pattern is not found, the substitution `re.sub(':', ':\n', s)` is made, replacing all `':'` in `s` with `':\n'`.

**What you probably want to do is either:**
1) Combine a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` with a negative lookahead `(?!...)` in your pattern to define a pattern which describes "colons but not if it's a time".
**or**
2) Search the string for a colon, then search the region around that match to see if the match is part of a time; if not, replace that item.

Certainly (1) is more efficient, but implementing (2) will help you understand why your solution isn't working.

This may be helpful:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search

**Solution to #1:**
The complete match pattern you're looking to replace should be:
`(?<!(\b[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm))?\b)`
So your one-liner would be:
`s = re.sub(r'(?<!(\b[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm))?\b)', ':\n', s)`
(Aren't regular expressions just *so* aesthetically pleasing?)

Try plugging it in here to test: https://www.debuggex.com/
(Remember to switch to `Python` in the dropdown menu.)

**EDIT:**
I forgot Python's lookbehinds have to be fixed width. A sloppy fix is to use the pattern:
`(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm))?\b)`
The caveat here is that it recognizes "garbage like11:45 and whatnot" as containing a time, but correctly identifies that "garbage like1:45 and whatnot" does not contain a time.

**EDIT #2:**
A little further checking shows that Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds *at all*, so many online regex testers might fail to execute this, even if you toggle them into Python mode.

Comment: What is \b at the end for?

Comment: That's to match a word boundary. It's there to ensure that your time is actually a time, and not jumbled into some other garbage, such as a MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
>>> re.sub('(?=\D):(?<=\D)',':\n',s)
"something blah blah:\n but it isn't 4:00 or 16:00 yet, how should we do this:\n that's it"
```

Which will match colons only if they are preceded and followed by a non-numeric (`\D`) character, using the `?=` and `?<=` [lookaround assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: How do I do conditionals? Say I want to split on either "。」"or" 。" (but not twice on "。」")

Comment: Not sure I get your new question, but you can use `|` in regex: `re.split('。」|。', s)`

Comment: yes, that works, but this way I don't get to keep either of the delimiters.