# REGEX: Chain multiple negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex

Regexes are just headaches.  I want to chain two negative lookbehind and negative lookahead REGEXes together.

First one:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm)|(a.m)|(p.m)|(a.m.)|(p.m.))?\b)',':\n',s)
```

Second one:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!([ps][tp])):(?!([\/][\/]))',':\n',s)
```

They both work separately, and add `\n` if they are not true. One is for time and the other is for URLs. How would I add them together so that `\n` is added right after a colon if the colon doesn't belong to a URL nor time.

This was the first part of my question:
[How to split string with colons but not if it is a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346726/how-to-split-string-with-colons-but-not-if-it-is-a-time/53346978#53346978)

Comment: FYI: `\b` inside character class means `backspace`, do you really want that?

Comment: Isn't [\b] backspace?    I thought \b is for word boundaries -> (Explanation)  Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either order).

Comment: INSIDE a character class, `[\b]` means backspace. `\b` is not a character, it is a zero-length assertion that match a word boundary.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53348053/edit) and add some test cases, input strings and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going the long way and using sub to mend the broken URLs that were broken apart by the previous negative lookbehind and negative lookahead regex. Ugh.

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<!([0-1\b][0-9]|[2][0-3])):(?!([0-5][0-9])((?i)(am)|(pm)|(a.m)|(p.m)|(a.m.)|(p.m.))?\b)',':\n',s,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
reg = re.compile(re.escape('http:\n//'), re.IGNORECASE)
reg1 = re.compile(re.escape('https:\n//'), re.IGNORECASE)
reg.sub('http://', s)
reg.sub('https://', s)
```

Comment: `.` means any character, you have to escape it `\.` if you want to match a dot.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks